# How to generate right actions for html forms with formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm have a little question, anybody please answer.
I generate form with formtastic something like this

semantic_form_for @some, :url => {:action => :do_something}

it generates me the action for form like this:
/some/2/do_something

I want it to generate action like this:
/some/2/do_something?#code

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Formtastic's `semantic_form_for` wraps around Rails' `form_for`, which, under the hood, uses standard Rails URL helpers and conventions. In this case, the convention you're probably interested in is URL generation from hashes like { :action => "bah" }, in which case you should check out the Rails documentation on `url_for`, which allows for an `:anchor` option:

```
url_for(:action => "foo", :anchor => 'bah')
# => /testing/foo#bah
```